# Create a BufferedImage from a Raster

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, raster

Simply I have a raster of an image and I want to make a `BufferedImage` of it.

```
Raster raster = someObject.getAsRaster();
BufferedImage bi = ?
```

How can I make a `BufferedImage` with suitable `ColorModel` so the image is shown properly?

Comment: You will need a `WritableRaster` to create a `BufferedImage`, using `new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null)`. What a suitable `ColorModel`might be, depends on the pixel data in the raster. What format/pixel layout does it use?

Comment: I mean compatible color model corresponding to the raster in such a way that image does not change.

Comment: I mean a color model compatible with a tiff image!

Comment: Pretty much any color model is compatible with TIFF.. What does your raster look like? What sample model does it use? What is the transfer type? How many color components? Does it have alpha?

Answer (score 3):

What a suitable `ColorModel` might be, depends on the pixel data in the raster. Here are some common variants:

- If the raster contains interleaved or banded samples in `byte` (8 bits) or `ushort` (16 bits) format, a `ComponentColorModel` will work. You will need to specify the data type, color space and wether or not the data contains alpha and if the alpha is premultiplied or not.
- If the raster is in "packed" format, you typically need a `DirectColorModel`. Again, you will need to know details about the raster for the colors to be correct.
- If the raster contains a single component that represents indexes into a lookup table, you will need an `IndexColorModel` with the correct lookup table.

There is no "one-size-fits-all" solution here, but the code will look something like this:

```
Raster raster = ...; // Your raster
ColorModel colorModel = ...; // A suitable color model (see above)

WritableRaster writableRaster = raster.createCompatibleWritableRaster();
writableRaster.setDataElements(0, 0, raster);

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(colorModel, writableRaster, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the constructor

```
BufferedImage(ColorModel cm, WritableRaster raster, boolean isRasterPremultiplied, Hashtable<?,?> properties)
```

If you provide more info on how you get the raster I can be more helpful